# Implementation of total correlation of assets in R

Tags: portfolio-management, correlation

I am trying to implement the (average) total correlation of assets, which is discussed [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8689/average-correlation-of-index-portfolio) and [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33656/what-is-the-total-correlation-between-assets-in-a-portfolio) in R. Specifically, I am looking at $\rho_{av(1)}$ and  $\rho_{av(2)}$:

$$
\rho_{av(1)} = \frac{2 \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j>i}^N w_i w_j \rho_{i, j}}{1 -  \sum_{i=1}^N w_i^2}
$$

$$
\rho_{av(2)} = \frac{\sigma^2 - \sum_{i=1}^N w_i^2\sigma_i^2}{2 \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j>i}^N w_i w_j \sigma_i \sigma_j}
$$

So far, I have the following code:

```
set.seed(123)
a = rnorm(100, 0, 0.02)
b = rnorm(100, 0, 0.03)
c = rnorm(100, 0, 0.04)
dt = cbind(a, b, c)
wg = runif(ncol(dt))
wg = wg/sum(wg)
wg = round(wg, digits = 3)

options(scipen = 999)
cv = cov(dt)
VARs = diag(cv)
cr = cor(dt)
length(wg)

sum_1 = 0
for (i in 1 : length(wg) ) {
  for (j in 2 : length(wg) ) {
    sum_1 = sum_1 + 2 * wg[i] * wg[j] * cr[i, j]
  }}
rho_1 = sum_1/(1 - sum(wg^2))

sum_2 = 0
for (i in 1 : length(wg) ) {
  for (j in 2 : length(wg) ) {
    sum_2 = sum_2 + 2 * wg[i] * wg[j] * sqrt(VARs[i]) * sqrt(VARs[j])
  }}

PV = t(wg) %*% cv %*% wg
ss = sum(wg^2 * VARs)
rho_2 = (PV - ss)/sum_2

rhos = c(rho_1, rho_2)
rhos
```

And the results are:

```
[1]  1.388473356 -0.004104948
```

I expected these two to be close to each other. I think there might be an error in my code. I would appreciate if somebody could verify the code.

Thanks.

Comment: the inner of each of your for loops should be `for(j in i+1 : length(wg))`, you are double counting the total variance, and since one is a numerator, an the other a denominator, it's going to push the two father away from each other. I would expect that to only account for a factor of 4 difference though, which is much less than what you have. Additionally, the first number is clearly wrong -> average correlation > 1? i don't think so.

Comment: in that case my correlation matrix ref gets out of bounds ... Exactly, it should be between `[-1; 1]`.

Comment: try `for(j in min(i+1, length(wg)) : length(wg))`...

Comment: got closer: `0.10906278; -0.01044804`. I think there is still something wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected original code (thanks @will):

```
 sum_1 = 0
  for (i in 1 : (length(wg) - 1) ) {
    for (j in  min(i+1, length(wg)) : length(wg) ) {
      sum_1 = sum_1 + 2 * wg[i] * wg[j] * cr[i, j]
    }}
  rho_11 = sum_1/(1 - sum(wg^2))

  sum_2 = 0
  for (i in 1 : (length(wg) - 1) ) {
    for (j in  min(i+1, length(wg)) : length(wg) ) {
      sum_2 = sum_2 + 2 * wg[i] * wg[j] * sqrt(VARs[i]) * sqrt(VARs[j])
    }}

  PV = t(wg) %*% cv %*% wg
  ss = sum(wg^2 * VARs)
  rho_22 = (PV - ss)/sum_2
```

A vectorized version:

```
  # double summation in numerator (including multiplier 2)
  diag(cr) <- 0
  double_sum.1 <- c(crossprod(wg, cr %*% wg))

  # single summation in denominator
  single_sum.1 <- c(crossprod(wg))
  rho_1 = double_sum.1/(1 - single_sum.1)


  # single summation in numerator
  single_sum.2 <- c(crossprod(wg * sqrt(diag(cv))))
  # double summation in denominator
  double_sum.2 <- sum(tcrossprod(wg * sqrt(diag(cv)))[upper.tri(diag(length(wg)))])
  PV = t(wg) %*% cv %*% wg
  rho_2 = (PV - single_sum.2)/ (2 * double_sum.2)
```

And the comparison of the two methods (initially they were way off):
[image]